# How to open an activity of one application inside another application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

I want to open an activity of one application inside another application
for that I am doing

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.audiopreferences.SystemAudioSettings"));

context.startActivity(intent);
```

if i execute above Im getting the below Exception

```
id=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fac930)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2741): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.audiopreferences.SystemAudioSettings } from ProcessRecord{414c0b58 2741:com.dea600.radioapp/u0a10071} (pid=2741, uid=10071) not exported from uid 1000
E/AndroidRuntime
```

Comment: refer this link
 http://hmkcode.com/android-start-another-activity-of-another-application/

Comment: user ApplicationManager and start the activity. This will handle most of the security measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:exported="true"; // Have to include it in the manifest file - activity to be used across multiple applications
Example 

     <activity
         android:name="com.example1.utility.MainActivity"
         android:exported="true"
         android:label="@string/app_name" />

Using MAinActivity from Another application

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setClassName("com.example.utility", "com.example1.utility.MainActivity");
   context.startActivity(intent3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open a settings activity from the system. You'll have a better chance of using the actual "action" for that activity.
Try

```
context.startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.SOUND_SETTINGS"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```